# gradle, Could not expand ZIP appcompat-v7:19.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-appcompat

I have a problem with Android Studio and Gradle to import `appcompat-v7`.

So here is my `src/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.0.1'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            packageName "com.test"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    
    apt {
        arguments {
            resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName
            androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
        // The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    
        // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
        // The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    
        // android annotations
        compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
        apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP '/opt/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.0.1/appcompat-v7-19.0.1.aar'.
```

Comment: Make sure the .aar file is there in the directory mentioned in error. it might be possible that your file is currpted, You can delete the m2repository and download it again.

Comment: The path is correct. I've tried to delete the m2repository and dowload it again but the error is still here.

Comment: chek my answer and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Does --stacktrace give more information?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems the issue is with directories permissions .

Check and try following things :

- Check whether you have write access on both the **android sdk** and
  **Android Studio** directories.
- if you are on Windows OS, also try to run Android Studio as Administrator by right clicking on the Studio's icon, .

Comment: Exactly. It was a permission problem on my ubuntu OS. In fact, my projects are stored on other partition and this project was created by root. I have modified my /etc/fstab to add the right uid and now everything is ok.

Comment: great @Youngjae , it makes me feel good when my contribution help somebody.

Comment: @aat can you please more widely explain what you did? I have same issue. I checked partition permissions and they seems to be ok. Usually I'm setting write permission to full project-dir but it help only temporary and then after some time repeating again.

Comment: @grub- Honnestly, I don't really remember what I did. Since the last time, I've installed a new OS and I have not the problem anymore ...

Comment: In my case (working on a Mac), I did have the wrong permissions on /Applications/Android (it was owned by root instead of my user), but also the build directory on my project was owned by root (I built on the command line using sudo probably, and then was getting this error when building on Android Studio) which was causing this error.

Comment: Any suggestions which file permissions will fail? On my Ubuntu I have 777 on the project and reading from /opt/android-studio/ and writing to ./grade/ also is possible... But my only solution to solve the issue so far, was `sudo ./studio.sh`.

Comment: After running the Android Studio as administrator, once, building as non-root user works. As long, as I won't click "Clean Projekt"...

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add my experience. I was getting this error for a kafka jar

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not expand ZIP '/home/srangwal/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.9.2/0.8.2.0/f9e44ac2d80afee7d5696f11814e6a65af5a380a/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.0.jar'.
> Could not copy zip entry /home/srangwal/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.9.2/0.8.2.0/f9e44ac2d80afee7d5696f11814e6a65af5a380a/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.0.jar!kafka/consumer/ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$addPartitionTopicInfo$1.class to '/home/srangwal/work-projects/griffin/build/tmp/expandedArchives/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.0.jar_7e6mtfrbv2j9f9v18u5gsfe9q/kafka/consumer/ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$addPartitionTopicInfo$1.class'.
```

To debug, I tried to touch the file that gradle was trying to create, since permissions of all my directories were fine

```
touch '/home/srangwal/work-projects/griffin/build/tmp/expandedArchives/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.0.jar_7e6mtfrbv2j9f9v18u5gsfe9q/kafka/consumer/ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$addPartitionTopicInfo$1.class'
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/srangwal/work-projects/griffin/build/tmp/expandedArchives/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.0.jar_7e6mtfrbv2j9f9v18u5gsfe9q/kafka/consumer/ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$addPartitionTopicInfo$1.class’: File name too long
```

I was getting this error because I was working on an encrypted filesystem in ubuntu and the **encrypted filesystem did not allow very long filenames**.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on *UNIX, you can run this command from the Android Studio command line

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /your/project/path
```

Comment: When I try this (Windows 7) I just get `'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I've now posted the problem/question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921786/android-studio-sudo-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-ope

Comment: @ChandlerSwift and macOS

Comment: I have similar problem (Could not expand ZIP  XXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/android.arch.lifecycle/runtime/XXX), this works well, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these Steps and make Build Successful

1. cd android **`cd android/`**
2. gradlew clean  **`./gradlew clean`**
3. cd ..
4. react-native run-android

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I've tried to build project in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 and my multi-module project today.
Not very good solution, but I've unchecked "Compile independent modules in parallel (may require larger heap space)" and problem disappeared.
Moreover, Gradle configuration for my project probably isn't ideal (but i can still successfully build project via command line) and i'm checking weak places.

Answer (score 2):

I found [someone with the same problem here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-expand-zip-file-using-jar/17536).

The solution - albeit a **temporary** one - is to downgrade from Gradle 2.1.0 to 2.0.0 in my project's build.gradle file.

Comment: This actually worked for me, co incidentally i had the problem with the same jar nxpnfclib and hence this solution worked.

Comment: @monotheist Did you ever find a better solution? (I'm still getting this same issue with Gradle 2.1.2, so am currently stuck on Gradle 2.0.0 .)

Comment: not yet, are u facing the problem with the same lib file? or different?

Comment: Same lib file - nxpnfclib.jar .

Comment: looks like the lib has a problem with 2.1.2, only NXP can fix it in their lib code

Comment: After a very protracted conversation with one of the NXP technical guys, they now have an intermediate release - https://nxp.app.box.com/s/hmbwjzac6jc9gw2qjkd9xtxs745me4s9 - which they say will work with Android Studio 2.1.2 . I expect the official release will be in the near future.

Comment: Anyone else also having this other (new) problem with `nxpnfclib.jar`?... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083338/android-studio-erroruncaught-translation-error-com-android-dx-cf-code-simexc

Comment: Incidentally, NXP have now changed over from `nxpnfclib.jar` to the **Tap Linx** library - which, unfortunately, also has its issues... :-/

Answer (score 2):

Guys this "COULD" be the problem that your Library is not compatible with the gradle version as it was with me. So I reduced the gradle version and it worked. I suggest that you try changing your gradle version and then build again.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a windows permission problem.
The project was created from Cygwin, and all folders had strange permissions

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Ubuntu user and I had the same problem. I followed pyus13's answer and I gave the write permissions to the **project folder** instead of giving it to **android-studio** and **android-sdk-linux**. Also, the command
`sudo chmod 7777 /your/project/path`
didn't work. But,
`sudo chmod 757 -R /your/project/path`
worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu user here; I stumbled across this problem after backing up my library on a mounted USB, then finding that the permissions had been changed on the project folder after reverting from a backup.

To restore access, I peformed the following steps:

1. Allow R/W access to the Android project folder. `sudo chmod -R 777 ./MyProjectDir`
2. Open the project in Android Studio. After gradle has finished indexing, `clean` the build.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with our own library. The final .aar contained a non valid .so filename inside.

Cleanup all the dependencies and rebuilt fixed the issue.

I found the issue by enabling --stacktrace with Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with the folder that the file was being unzipped *to*. Deleting that and running the build again sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

Run `cd android && gradlew clean && cd.. && react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the AAR too large,and i don't use the git lfs

Answer (score -2):

- If you are using jdk1.8., Remove it.
- Installing jdk1.7.

Comment: Worked for me, I had the same error, the project I was working on was meant to run on jdk 1.7 and my environment had jdk 1.8.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Downgrading was the last thing I did, but turned out it was what was required. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

i think i can help you,you should try to remove your project to your Ubuntu user directory,like /home/username/, then, reload your project and work it.