# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library'.

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I' m using Android Studio,after upgrading to preview 7 i'm getting this error on gradle sync projecr,
Error:Execution failed for task **':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library'.

> Could not expand ZIP '/home/sultan_mirza/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar'.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gradle, Could not expand ZIP appcompat-v7:19.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497181/gradle-could-not-expand-zip-appcompat-v719-0-1)

Comment: @mico how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check the answers in the link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with directories permissions .

- Check whether you have write access on both the **android sdk** and
  **Android Studio** directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, check that your build folder is not "read-only" !