# Android studio error execution failed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library'.

> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gradle, Could not expand ZIP appcompat-v7:19.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497181/gradle-could-not-expand-zip-appcompat-v719-0-1)

Comment: Upgrade your gradle. That could be the issue. [See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064060/react-native-build-error-execution-failed-for-task-react-native-mapspreparec)

Answer (score 1):

Write permission may be the issue.Please check the below link.you will get some more information.

[gradle, Could not expand ZIP appcompat-v7:19.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497181/gradle-could-not-expand-zip-appcompat-v719-0-1)