# React-native build error: Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library'. > Could not expand ZIP

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I created a new `react-native` project on a Windows 10 system, installed the `react-native-maps` package and `rnpm link`, but when starting the project I get a Build failed error.

What is causing this problem?

```
react-native init myapp
npm install react-native-maps --save
rnpm link
react-native run-android
```

**Versions**

```
react-native-cli: 1.3.0
react-native: 0.39.1
node: v7.2.1
npm: 3.10.10
```

[image]

**Error**

```
JS server already running.
Running C:\Users\y\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:compileLint
:react-native-maps:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-maps:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\y\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v
7\23.0.1\appcompat-v7-23.0.1.aar'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.247 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

(node:8824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read prop
erty 'message' of undefined
(node:8824) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem. Try to open your project in Android Studio. In right corner there are some notifications, you need to update Android build-tools and platform-tools.

Comment: Updated gradle from 2.2.3 to 2.14.1. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing such issues quite often
this is windows problem. As I understand it happens because expanding zip takes too much time and builder fails. 
I've minimized such warnings by moving project folder to ssd and by adding project folder to exceptions for my anti-virus software

just execute 'react-native run-android' more and more and it will be finished in some time

Comment: I am using SSD (Samsung 850 Pro) and a 6 core (12 threads) 4.6 GHz Intel processor on a clean Windows 10 system with no antivirus. Will try running it multiple times to see if it can unzip successfully

Comment: Is there anyway to increase the timeout for the unzip operation?

Comment: have no idea. I haven't investigated this deeply
reexecuting run-android works for me (each time I see different ZIPs that couldn't be expanded) and after several tries build became successfull
while executing next run-android commands this ZIPs are not expanded so problem is not critical for me

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the following according to this [issue](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/880)

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Comment: after so much of effort, your answer helped me. ;-)

Comment: Solution Works for Me . https://github.com/infinitered/ignite/issues/941

Answer (score 0):

on windows

```
cd android 
gradlew clean 
cd ..
react-native run-android
```

or

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```