# Unable to unzip appcompat files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72530Library'.
>
>   > Unable to unzip 'C:\Users\Yankee\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.3.0\appcompat-v7-25.3.0.aar'
>   >     to
>   >     'C:\Users\Yankee.android\build-cache\272ee28f948939f72511c236105f144ee9285543\output'

I updated Android Studio and it came up with this message. However that was for the 24.2.1 version. I have no clue what's going wrong. One of the solutions I found here was to change all versions to 25 (the most recent one) in the app. So I changed everything in the app file to versions 25. However, it's still giving me the same error after I sync. the project.

If it helps, the are 3 files and 1 map in the `output` where it's unzipping to. Map is named "jars" and the files "AndroidManifest" (the xml-doc) , "annotations" (ZIP) and "R" (textdoc)

Does anyone know the solution and why it's unable to unzip?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21497181/1440565 for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today.
just delete the folder `C:\Users\Yankee\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository`

And Update it again.