# Error with expanding zip file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It seems that every time I try to either create a new app or open an old app, I receive this error.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72530Library'.

> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\Jenna\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.3.0\appcompat-v7-25.3.0.aar'.

I have no idea how to fix it and it happens pretty much every time I log onto Android Studio. If someone could please help or at least lead me in some direction to find an answer I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: does any of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497181/gradle-could-not-expand-zip-appcompat-v719-0-1 help ?

Comment: No it didn't. I tried running as an administrator and that didn't seem to work.